# Does Google Apps Script support signed OAuth requests?

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, hmacsha1

OAuth wants requests for "protected resources" to be signed by the consumer using a hash such as HMAC-SHA1 or RSA-SHA1.

Does Google Apps Script support request hashing?  I RTFM, and tried the demo (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/twitter_tutorial) but... no joy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try Utilities.computeDigest() Utilities.computeHmacSignature() and Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature()

Documentation at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_utilities